# sql insert table

Tags: sql, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO etaty (nazwa, placa_max, placa_min) VALUES ('Gnojki', 20, 10)
INSERT INTO etaty (nazwa, placa_max, placa_min) VALUES ('Gnojki Pasiaste', 40, 30)
INSERT INTO etaty (nazwa, placa_max, placa_min) VALUES ('Gnojki Pasiastowate', 60, 50)
INSERT INTO etaty (nazwa, placa_max, placa_min) VALUES ('Gnojki Malutkie', 80, 70)
INSERT INTO etaty (nazwa, placa_max, placa_min) VALUES ('Gnojuszki', 100, 90)
```

I got a error "SQL command not properly ended", in the second line. I can not deal with it.

Comment: You need to end each statement with `;`

Comment: ...unless the delimiter has been altered to something else..

Comment: And this most likely also depends on the **concrete** RDBMS in use .....

Answer (score 1):

to execute multiple SQL statements batch together like that, you need to separate each query with a semicolon.

```
INSERT INTO etaty (nazwa, placa_max, placa_min) VALUES ('Gnojki', 20, 10);
INSERT INTO etaty (nazwa, placa_max, placa_min) VALUES ('Gnojki Pasiaste', 40, 30);
INSERT INTO etaty (nazwa, placa_max, placa_min) VALUES ('Gnojki Pasiastowate', 60, 50);
INSERT INTO etaty (nazwa, placa_max, placa_min) VALUES ('Gnojki Malutkie', 80, 70);
INSERT INTO etaty (nazwa, placa_max, placa_min) VALUES ('Gnojuszki', 100, 90);
```